# access xml from object

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

So I have a drag and drop operation, and the data being dragged is some XML. My drophandler looks like this:

```
protected function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
    var item:XML = XML(event.dragSource.dataForFormat("itemsByIndex"));
    Alert.show(item);
}
```

The alert looks like this:

[image: Alert with xml]

How do can I for example get the ID of this XML? In an alert for example.

Comment: `Alert.show(item.artist.id)` http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `id` property with `item.id`, the `name` with `item.name`, etc. There are a few resources online to learn e4x, which is the easiest way of manipulating XML in AS3.